# Api not found on VPS, works on local, ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am tying to deploy API which I built in web application, which is not MVC, so API controller code is in App_Code, Global.asax.cs has routing code:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "MyAPI",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{pakackagename}/{departure}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    pakackagename = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional,
                    departure = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

this code is in Application start in Global.asax.cs
in web.config I have following settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--MITSU-->
    <!--add name="ReservationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=False; User ID=xxxxx; Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--BLUE-->
    <!--<add name="ReservationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=False; User ID=xxxx; Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--LOCAL-->
    <add name="ReservationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=False; User ID=xxxxx; Password=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web> 
          <trust level="Full" /> 
  </system.web> 
  <system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">

      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <machineKey validationKey="xxxxx" decryptionKey="xxxxxx" validation="SHA1" />
    <!--
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
          symbols into the compiled page. Because this
          affects performance, set this value to true only
          during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" batch="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <!--SAMPLE-->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="30" />

    <!--<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>-->
    <!--<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1; integrated security=true;" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>-->

    <!--MITSU-->
    <!--<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx; Integrated Security=false; User ID=xxxx; Password=xxxxx;" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>-->

    <!--LOCAL-->
    <!--<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=xxxx; Integrated Security=false; User ID=xxxx; Password=xxxxx;" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>-->
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="R_PT_P" value="show=false;Description=Region-Product Type-Product" />
    <add key="R_P" value="show=false;Description=Region-Product" />
    <add key="P" value="show=false;Description=Product" />
    <add key="PT_R_P" value="show=true;Description=Product Type-Region-Product" />
    <add key="SMTPServer" value="xxxxxx.in"/>
    <add key="SMTPUserId" value="xxxx@xxxxxx.in" />
    <add key="SMTPPwd" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <add key="LockDuration" value="10"/>
    <!--This value is in minutes-->

    <!--<add key="username" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="password" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="secret" value="xxxx" />-->
    <!--<add key="mercid" value="xxxx" />-->

    <!--Testing
    <add key="mercid" value="xxxxx" />
    <add key="username" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="password" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="secret" value="xxxxx" />-->               

    <!--Production-->
    <add key="cName" value="xxxxxx" />
    <add key="cAddress" value="xxxxxx" />
    <add key="cEmail" value="xxxxx@xxxxxx.in" />
    <add key="cPhoneNo" value="+91xxxxxxx" />
    <add key="cMobile" value="+91xxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="cLogo" value="http://xxxxxxxxxx.in/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx.xxxx" />
    <add key="ccEmail" value="xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com" />

    <add key="username" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="password" value="xxxxx" />
    <add key="secret" value="xxxxx" />
    <add key="mercid" value="xxxxx" />

    <add key="FtpUid" value="xxxxx"/>
    <add key="FtpPwd" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    <add key="EncryptionAllowed" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The problem is with opening url on server, when I open http://localhost:xxxx/api/Values/xxxx/xxxx , then it works and returns XML, but when I use http://example.com/api/Values/xxxx/xxxx/ it says 404 not found.

I tried everything on the internet, but still no help.

Comment: Could you please show us the deployed folder structure?

Comment: @Div the deployed is present in App_Code of project, there we have all files like ValuesController, Global.asax.cs, etc for API, Global.asax.cs has routing codes in App start . but not configuration as MVC like config. somewhat similar to this -- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-web-api-in-existing-web-form-application/

Comment: How are you calling API? using an ajax or postman?

Comment: Simple url postman, also browser directly

Comment: Okay, without digging the issue, cannot say anything !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created New WebAPI project and deployed on a subdomain. Its much better that way.